# NHibernate eager loading needed here?

Tags: .net, nhibernate, lazy-loading

I have problems using NHibernate (Version 3.2, with Visual Studio 2010).

I try to load tasks on a page. A task is attached to an employee (by foreign key).

class:

```
public class Task
{                                   
    private Employee employee;

    public virtual Employee Employee
    {
        get
        {
            return employee;
        }

        set
        {
            employee = value;
        }
    }
}
```

Repository-method:

```
public List<Task> GetAll()
    {
        using (ISession session = Configuration.SessionProvider.OpenSession())
        {
            var tasks = session
                .CreateCriteria(typeof(Task))
                .List<Task>()
                .ToList();

            return tasks;
        }
    }
```

mapping:

```
<hibernate-mapping xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2" namespace="Test1.Domain.Model" assembly="Test1.Domain">
<class name="Task" table="Task">
    <id name="Id" column="TaskId">
        <generator class="identity"/>
    </id>

    <many-to-one name="Employee" class="Employee" column="EmployeeId"/>

</class>
```

page:

```
<asp:GridView runat="server" ID="taskGrid" AutoGenerateColumns="false">
        <Columns>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Id" HeaderText="Task ID" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Employee" HeaderText="Employee" />
        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>

taskGrid.DataSource = taskRepository.GetAll();
taskGrid.DataBind();
```

Whenever I open the page in the browser, a get an error:

```
Initializing[Test1.Domain.Model.Employee#1]-Could not initialize proxy - no Session.
```

because a proxy is set for the employee-property of the tasks.

The same with debugging step over (F10). But when I step into the GetAll()-method (F11), the employees of the tasks are fully loaded (no proxy).

I am confused why NHibernate reacts differently on different debugging techniques. What interests me mainly is

1. Do I need eager loading in my case?
2. Why is the loading of related entities dependent on the way I debug NHibernate?

Answer (score 2):

You can use QueryOver for it:

```
Session.QueryOver<Task>()
 .Fetch(task => task.Employee).Eager
 .TransformUsing(Transformers.DistinctRootEntity)
 .List<Task>();
```

This query get all tasks with real employee objects (not proxy)